# Cannot add comments with Facebook plugin using W10 and MS Edge

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm using W10 and MS Edge browser and cannot add FB comments. It does work on the same machine when using IE. And, using Edge, I can add FB comments on other pages. My test page is http://testing.mcgurkin.net/fbTesting.html. The page is very simple, just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (
            function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=304916296240772&version=v2.4";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
            (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
        );
    </script>
    <div>Facebook Testing</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://testing.mcgurkin.net/fbTesting.html" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://testing.mcgurkin.net/fbTesting.html" data-numposts="5"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In IE, works fine. In Edge, it says log in to post, I log in, FB page opens fine in a new window. But returning to the original page, it still says log in to post.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I would check the Javascript console on IE and Edge, see if you get any errors there. If so, please file a bug report under developers.facebook.com/bugs with detailed reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to init the sdk. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.6'
    });
  };
        (
            function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=304916296240772&version=v2.6";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
            (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
        );
    </script>
    <div>Facebook Testing</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://testing.mcgurkin.net/fbTesting.html" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://testing.mcgurkin.net/fbTesting.html" data-numposts="5"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```